# Whonix - How to get Java Plugin installed/working on Iceweasel? + GUI, Troubleshooting questions

Tags: configuration, whonix, client, pre-tor-proxy

I need help installing or messing with certain things on Whonix.

Most important is getting Java to work on it in the browser. I've installed Iceweasel and Chromium, and JRE 8 and JDK6 (long story...), but I don't know how to get a Java plugin installed and working. If I could just install things by double clicking on them or right clicking to get a menu option of having them run as administrator this would be a lot less trouble, which is why I pose this question first. Ubuntu's like this too until you change a settings item or two reachable within the GUI, but I can't figure out a way to do this AT ALL on Debian/KDE/Whonix!

- So, how do you install Java and its plugin properly on Whonix step by step? I installed Iceweasel and Chromium after realizing that Java doesn't work on Whonix's patched Tor browser, so is that it?
- So, how exactly do you install things via the GUI interface like through
  double clicking on it as in windows, or can you even make it let you?
  And how do you also, for example, do things like run installation files as
  'administrator' or root I guess in the case of the Debian KDE Whonix
  is based on from the GUI? I'm learning to use commands like "cd", ".." and so forth, but they're still kind of annoying and I'm worried not all apps are best installed via command line.

Secondly, I seem to have issues getting Sip phone clients working on Whonix. I've set Linphone and Jitsi up, but Linphone just says registration is failing and Jitsi's doesn't ever seem to connect either but with no error warning for either, even though the Sip registrars I'm using have worked on my desktop via VPN in the past. I also have issues with setting up VMWare Horizon. It installed seemingly successfully via the commandline according to some instructions I reviewed for Debian but it won't open.

- Is the problem that the Sip registrars don't want to accept
  transmissions via Tor?
- And is VMWare Horizon not working due to some harsh
  limitation of Java on Whonix done for privacy reasons or can Horizon
  be made to work on it without too much trouble? If these DO work
  please link any step-by-steps if you know of any.

Thanks

Comment: They want 1 good question per thread here, so others can benefit from answers. So I guess this thread will be closed. Just briefly. | Sip: The Tor network does not support UDP. Sip by default uses UDP. This clashes. For instructions on how to make it work, see https://www.whonix.org/wiki/VoIP. | Whonix VMware -> unmaintained -> See: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/VMware | To get root, open a terminal (Konsole) use `kdesudo` followed by `/path/to/app`. | Tor Browser: Whonix does NOT patch it. The Tor Project patches it.

Comment: [0005-Block-all-plugins-except-flash.patch](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/tree/src/current-patches/firefox/0005-Block-all-plugins-except-flash.patch)

Comment: See also: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Browser_Plugins